# How to create multipart fromdata parameter for file upload from local in Swagger editor

Tags: yaml, postman, swagger, multipartform-data, swagger-editor

I am Creating swagger Ui for my api using swagger editor, my api is post method having body>fromdata>file (uploads file from local) parameter, now I need to create same parameter in swagger editor

I found below code for fileupload but it is  throwing error asking additional properties

````
   /upload:
     post:
       summary: Uploads a file.
       consumes:
         - multipart/form-data
       parameters:
         - in: formData
           name: upfile
           type: file ```


Please help
````

Comment: Do you use `openapi: 3.x.x` or `swagger: '2.0'`? Can you post your entire YAML and a screenshot of the error?

Comment: Hi Helen, i understand difference previously I used Swagger editor 3.0 but later i realised only Swagger editor 2.0 accepts Upfile parameter...

Comment: Hi Helen, i understand difference previously I used Swagger editor 3.0 but later i realised only Swagger editor 2.0 accepts Upfile parameter... Now I done with my task thanks for the response &&&& i have one more doubt how to generate client? If I generate client using Java, it Is downloading a zip file, but that is not extracting showing cannot complete the compressed (zipped) Error